# LINQ to Objects converting to list to display in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web-applications, linq-to-objects

I am trying to use LINQ to Objects to bind a list of books to a gridview. Author and Book are custom objects, where "Books" is defined in the Author class as a list.

```
    List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
    // list of authors/books is populated here
    var books = from s in authors
                       where s.LastName == "Jones"
                       select s.Books;

    GridView2.DataSource = books.AsEnumerable().Cast<Book>().ToList();
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

However I get the following error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. --->
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Book]' to type 'Book'.
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__aa`1.MoveNext()   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably you have 2 different Book types. One comes from webservice and the other is somewhere inside your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think the problem is that books is a collection.
So you actually get a collection of collections of books

```
// list of authors/books is populated here
var books = (from s in authors
                   where s.LastName == "Jones"
                   select s.Books).SelectMany(c=>c);
```

Using a [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/DA-DK/library/bb534336.aspx) 
will turn your collection of books collection into one of books :-)

You could also replease your `Cast` with the SelectMany:

```
 var books = from s in authors
                       where s.LastName == "Jones"
                       select s.Books;

    GridView2.DataSource = books.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an Idea, otherwise I think you have fine.
    var books = (from s in authors
                       where s.LastName == "Jones"
                       select s.Books).Tolist();
and pass this directly
     GridView2.DataSource = books ;
     GridView2.DataBind();

This might work..

Comment: That gives me the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Book>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Book>'

Comment: Do one thing. Please Paste the code of"// list of authors/books is populated here". Paste the code of binding this collection and also author class and it's defination. I think there is just type mismatch